# Background Image not working CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created 5 spans in one div and want to keep one background image for that div.

[image]

Background image is not coming properly, below is my code:

[**JSFiddle** link](https://jsfiddle.net/hpet5Lp2/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <span id="intro">Introduction<br>to APO MF</span>
        <span id="apo">APO<br>Diagnostic</span>
        <span id="result">Result of<br>CMP and<br>Maturity</span>
        <span id="discussion">Discussion<br>with CSL</span>
        <span id="annual">Annual<br>improvement<br>plan</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    width: 80%;
    background-image:url("http://author.confirmit.com/isa/EXMRFPJVOQHBOHMKEYPPDKDXOPCQIXPY/APO%20Diagnostic%20survey-VL/background.PNG");
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    padding-top:30px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#intro{
    background-color: #C0504D;
}
#apo{
    background-color: #9BBB59;
}
#result{
    background-color: #8064A2;
}
#discussion{
    background-color: #4BACC6;
}
#annual{
    background-color: #F79646;
}
```

Comment: not coming properly means what?

Comment: Image is not coming behind spans and only bottom part of image is appearing at some random position on page @ShudhanshShekhar

Comment: The image is displaying exactly as it should - according to your code (http://jsfiddle.net/16oLe33z/1/). How do you expect it to display?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `background-size: cover;` to your `div` style, your `image` width will fit your `div` width.

Add also `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-position: center;` to center and avoid repeat:

```
div{
    width: 80%;
    background-image: url("http://author.confirmit.com/isa/EXMRFPJVOQHBOHMKEYPPDKDXOPCQIXPY/APO%20Diagnostic%20survey-VL/background.PNG");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfL9v8sn/1/)

Hope this is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this
background-image: url("../http://author.confirmit.com/isa/EXMRFPJVOQHBOHMKEYPPDKDXOPCQIXPY/APO%20Diagnostic%20survey-VL/background.PNG");

or
background-image: url("./http://author.confirmit.com/isa/EXMRFPJVOQHBOHMKEYPPDKDXOPCQIXPY/APO%20Diagnostic%20survey-VL/background.PNG");

Comment: I am using it same way but background image should be appearing just being the spans I have created. @mukto

Comment: You can use background-size:cover; @Luthara

Answer (score 0):

change the css for div tag to

```
    div {
    width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image:url("http://author.confirmit.com/isa/EXMRFPJVOQHBOHMKEYPPDKDXOPCQIXPY/APO%20Diagnostic%20survey-VL/background.PNG");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```